# Ionic 4 Android App, unable to change background color of status bar

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm building an ionic 4 app and when running on android the status bar is black, which I want to change but I can't figure it out.

I've tried to change the preferences in the config.xml, OverlayWebView true and false and tried to just use the this.statusBar.backroundcolor... stuff. Nothing works.
the statusBar plugin is installed.

```
Config.xml:    
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#ffffff" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />


App.component.ts

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
  })
 export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
     this.initializeApp();
  }


  initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splashScreen.hide();
  this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
  this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
    });
   }
 }
```

I want to change the color of the status bar which displays time, battery level, etc. but no matter what I do it stays black.

Comment: Remove all line for statusBar. Just put this   this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff'); No need any changes in config.xml as well

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't work.

Comment: I face the same issue using above line that's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I now managed to change the color, but had to do it in Android Studio with android:statusBarColor. Still would be grateful for ways to do it in ionic.

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
 </style>


 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```